# Flutter - How can I change background color of the persistent navigation bar in real time?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, uinavigationcontroller, bottomnavigationview

Need to change backgroundColor settings of persistent navigation bar(
[https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar](https://%20https://pub.dev/packages/persistent_bottom_nav_bar) ) from white to black color in **real time** when I click some button on some page. How can I do that?

```
 class _BottomMenu extends State<BottomMenu> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        PersistentTabController _controller;
        _controller = PersistentTabController(initialIndex: 0);
        return PersistentTabView(
          context,
          controller: _controller,
          screens: _buildScreens(),
          items: _navBarsItems(),
          confineInSafeArea: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white, 
          handleAndroidBackButtonPress: true, 
          resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true, 
          stateManagement: false, 
          hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows: true,
          decoration: NavBarDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
            colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
          ),
          popActionScreens: PopActionScreensType.all,
          screenTransitionAnimation: ScreenTransitionAnimation(
            animateTabTransition: true,
            curve: Curves.ease,
             duration: Duration(milliseconds: 10),
          ),
          navBarStyle: NavBarStyle.style6   ,
        );
      }
    
    }
```